# Download entire web archive using terminal

Tags: downloads, wget

what I'm trying to do is download a whole web archive using wget. When I put something like `wget (website link)` using  HTTPs, it doesn't download everything, but when I put a specific file name, it downloads it.

Is there any way I can have the terminal try every possible combination, each ending in the file type, so that it downloads all the good stuff I need? Apparently, when I don't be specific, it refuses the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Snipperize](http://snipperize.todayclose.com/snippet/bash/Download-an-Entire-Website-with-Wget--111156/):

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links restrict-file-names=windows --domains website.org --no-parent www.example.com/foo/bar/
```

Comment: Didn't work... Fail.

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an error message?

Comment: I am trying to download all files from http://minecrafft.net/skin/ for my friend but it refuses the connection unless I enter a specific file name.

Comment: The url you provided doesn't work.

Comment: I meant "minecraft.net/skin/" apparantly, it was a typo.

Comment: Example: wget http://minecraft.net/skin/pigmine123.png

Comment: You can't do this unless you have a file or website which contains all the links you want to download. Bruteforcing would take ages and will get your IP address blocked in no time.

Comment: I tried bruteforcing, I didn't get IP banned...

Comment: I know it worked because the files kept coming, unfortunutely the code was taking 4ever to make.

Comment: Then what's the problem? Just bruteforce then and have your code ignore all 404 errors that wget encounters.